# relacion entre tablas, DUDA

Tags: base-de-datos

[image: Mi esquema conceptual]

Buen dia con todos, estoy haciendo un directorio telefonico con las sgtes consideraciones:

1.- Muchos teléfonos pertenecen a un departamento ( relacion 1:n)
2.- Un departamento tiene muchas o NINGUNA oficina

Pregunta:
1.-Esta bien la forma como relacione las entidades ( futuras tablas)?
2.-Debería relacionar teléfono con oficina?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: La relación es muy rara, en la realidad los teléfonos no están en el departamento, sino en una oficina concreta ¿no? Entonces, ¿por qué relacionas teléfonos con departamento y no simplemente con oficina?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que hay departamentos que NO tienen oficina alguna.

Comment: ¿Y cuando no tienen oficina, dónde tienen los teléfonos? Tienes que diseñar tus tablas pensando en la realidad, es muy simple si lo haces así, sino te pierdes en conceptos abstractos.

Comment: Claro que si incluimos teléfonos móviles o virtuales, entonces, los teléfonos podrían no estar en ninguna oficina (trabajadores remotos, quizás?). En todo caso, si se trata de un teléfono de piso, obviamente tiene que estar físicamente en algún lugar.

Comment: Yo no entiendo la pregunta. Tu dibujo hace lo que se pide. Entonces cual seria la duda? En tal caso, falta saber las reglas de relacion entre telefono y oficina

Comment: @jachguate en el caso que expones entraría otro ente, que sería el `empleado` que porta o que opera el teléfono. Por lo que el modelo de datos que presenta el OP sería incompleto. Para decidir sobre un modelo de datos hay que tener a la vista todas las entidades que participan en él y tener muy claro cuál es el contexto. Podríamos hablar de una oficina `central` (por defecto en cada `departamento`), de una oficina `virtual` que agruparía a todos los teléfonos remotos,  o de una oficina `movil`, etc... En definitiva, puede que falte contextualizar cosas en su pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano, estamos totalmente de acuerdo. Si lo dije, fue solo para hacer ver, justamente, que falta información y que la _realidad_ (me gusta llamarle "dominio del problema") debe estar acotada y mejor definida, pues la solución _apropiada_ siempre va a depender de cuál es el problema que se intenta resolver. Un saludo :)